# Is there a web application framework for Debian Linux based on C++ like .NET framework

Tags: c++, .net, linux, web

I have an existing application code-base under Linux which is in C++, I want to develop an web interface for this application, I am wondering if there is a good framework like ASP.NET in windows can handle this kind of development

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- ASP.NET - through Mono
- Sinatra - Ruby
- Ruby on Rails - Ruby
- Zend - PHP
- Kohana - PHP
- CakePHP - PHP
- Django - Python
- Play! - Java or Scala
- etc.

So everything what you can imagine. You must simply provide your app output to be readable through web.

Comment: Wt about I want directly call the method and function in the existing code base?

Comment: I don't like native code as web service but you can use for example Wt. It's not good idea but it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

For linux you can use WT, CPPcms or CGI scripts.

They aren't managed but and would probably be overkill but they are your C++ options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++.NET (C++/CLI) on GNU/Linux through Mono. So there is no alternative.

Comment: @Artyom The question said .NET Framework. C++/CLI is part of the .NET Framework and supports ASP.NET.

Comment: The problem is that he asks C++ on Linux not on Windows. So it is just not feasible to use C++ with Mono on Linux (because under mono you will have to use CLI only... no native code). So it would not work

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a web interface using [CppCMS](http://cppcms.com) C++ web framework.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at [ffead-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp), it works on linux and many other OS, provides an emebedded server, apache module and many other distinguishing features.